# Creating GUI for an arcgis project with python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, web-mapping, gui, html5

I am new to Python and been putting my hands around ArcGIS for a while. So I am wondering if it is possible to create a GUI for an ArcGIS project I did and compile it to a desktop application or web based application. Considering my core is HTML I was even thinking if it is possible with it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Please edit your answer to provide more detail on what you want and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Can you build standalone desktop app, or web app with python and ArcGIS? No, not really. What about adding GP services, tools, or scripts? Yes, that is doable.

You can create add-ins and scripts to launch in ArcGIS Desktop, and geoprocessing services to use with ArcGIS Server. You can read more about these below, as they may be what you are looking for.

Python Scripts in ArcGIS Desktop - http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-creating-script-tools.htm

Geoprocessing Services on ArcGIS Server - http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/what-is-a-geoprocessing-service-.htm

Why not a desktop app?
You might be able to hack a solution together using something using a GUI like Qt, and connect with ArcGIS with something like win32com, but that will require ArcGIS (and a License) to be installed on the users machine, there isn't much documentation on it, and there really are no benefits over using C#/C++ with ArcObjects SDK, or ArcGIS Runtime SDK, running with ArcEngine (or desktop). In addition you are likely violating the terms of Use. Python also doesn't compile very well.

Why not a web site?
It is possible, but it violates terms of use, and is overly complicated when ArcGIS server and other open source products exist (MapServer, GeoServer). I would recommend using those instead. I would look in to geoprocessing services.